# mongodb query need improvements

Tags: mongodb-query

for a given parameter, I am querying most recent record from collection like this:

```
query = {'id': parameter}
doc = collection.find_one(query, sort=[('updated_at',-1)])
```

How can I get most recent record for all 'id' present in collection in one query? For now, I am iterating over parameter and concatenating the output

**INPUT**: Collection has multiple record/documents like:

```
{
    id: "ABC",
    weight: 35, 
    updated_at: "2013-10-01T1:32:12.112Z" 
},
{
    id: "ABC",
    weight: 45, 
    updated_at: "2017-10-01T1:32:12.112Z" 
},
{
    id: "BAD",
    weight: 38, 
    updated_at: "2013-10-11T1:32:12.112Z" 
}
```

**Output**:

```
{
{
    id: "ABC",
    weight: 45, 
    updated_at: "2017-10-01T1:32:12.112Z" 
},
{
    id: "BAD",
    weight: 38, 
    updated_at: "2013-10-11T1:32:12.112Z" 
}
}
```

**Solution**: If I construct pipeline as shown below. what would be the implication of weight using $first

```
[
    { "$sort": { "id": 1, "updated_at": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "updated_at": { "$first": "$updated_at" },
        "weight": { "$first": "$weight" }

    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) if you want to do it in single query.
Try the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$id",
           maxWeight: { $max: "$weight" }
           recent: { $max: "$updated_at" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Here you group by '*id*' or '*parameter*' field.

Comment: I want to capture most recent date data and not the max data!!!

Comment: Can u differentiate between recent date and max date? For me, both are same.